Flaky Sediment in Hot Water
The last several weeks I have noticed black sediment (and more recently some tan sediment as well) in our tub when running the hot water. I am now noticing smaller amounts of sediment in the sinks and in the dishwasher too.
The particles do not smear. They are flaky, hard particles that leave no residue. We have a tankless water heater and our home is 6 years old. I have an infant and am so worried that the water could be toxic.


Water heaters with hard water usually need to flush out sediment every so often.  Usually not toxic(depending on amount), but does block screens/filters in time.

Sink faucets/dishwashers usually have fine screens in them.  Have you noticed any change in the flow of water out of them, maybe spraying a bit.

If you are worried about the content submit a sample to a water testing service or your State water agency.
This appears to be sediment. I have a whole house filter on my incoming water and then the refrigerator also has a filter.
I still get some small amounts of minerals precipitating in my drink cup that looks like white crystals but what you have looks like rust or scale from the pipes.
If you are concerned about the sediment run the water through a sediment filter pitcher like a Brita or similar.
